# I can't get the Java .Replace object to change my string depending on Scanner input

Tags: java, arrays

I am using a scanner to put a String value into currentGuess, then i have a method called 'alphabet' which contains a simple string of letters, i wanted to have a letter whether a,b,c that a user puts into a scanner, replacing the letter in the Alphabtet String with _ or taken.This doesn't happen anymore like it used to. I don't know what i did wrong. Underneath the 'scanner' is an object called "alphabet();" which checks your letters and updates the list with a return. The program is a resemblance of scrabble where a user enters a letter and that letter is removed from the alphabet. Only letters that get replaced are 'abcdefg'so 7, which is what the while loop is set to, but nothing else does, for some weird reason. If i set the first letter in the string to 'h', then type h, it will change that letter. I will include a small bit of the problem code and my entire code for those interested. I will be very happy if someone helps me out.

```
private static String alphabet()
{
    System.out.println("debugging:underneath alphabet string. >"+currentGuess+"<");
    for(int i=0;i<alphabet.toCharArray().length;i++){
            if(currentGuess.contains(alphabet.toCharArray()[i]+""))
            {   
                System.out.println("debugging: >"+currentGuess+"<");
                alphabet=alphabet.replace((alphabet.toCharArray()[i]+""), "test");
                
            }else if(currentGuess.contains(Vowels.toCharArray()[i]+""))
            {
            System.out.println("You have just entered a Vowel, board not affected.");
            }


import java.util.Scanner;
```

import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class scrabble{

    
    private static String alphabet = "[b][c][d][f][g][h][j][k][l][m]\n[n][p][q][r][s][t][v][w][x][y][z]";
    private static String currentGuess = "";
    private static String guessedLetters = "";
    private static String currentPlayer;
    private static int letterValue = 0;
    private static int playerNumber = 1;
    private static String playerTwo;
    private static String playerOne;
    private static String Response = "";
    private static int playerTwoScore = 0;
    private static int playerOneScore = 0;
    private static int playerTurnScore = 0;
    private static String playerLetter = "";
    private static int finalScores = 0;
    private static int duplicateLetterValue = 0;
    private static String Vowels = "[a][e][i][o][u]";
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nThis is the main console.");
    System.out.println("Type Y to begin or N to exit.");
    
    if(new Scanner(System.in).next().equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        System.out.println("Player one, enter your name: ");
        playerOne = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Player two, enter your name: ");
        playerTwo = scan.next();
        
        currentPlayer();
        startGame();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private static void startGame()
{
    int i=0;
    System.out.println("     <--Scrabble Board-->");
    System.out.print(alphabet()+"\n");
    System.out.println("\nNext Turn is: "+currentPlayer);
//if(currentGuess.equals("quit")){
    //if(currentGuess.equals("pass")){
        
        
for(i=0;i<7;i++){
    duplicateLetterValue=letterValue;
    guessedLetters+=currentGuess;
    playerLetter+=currentGuess;
    playerTurnScore+=letterValue;
    
    System.out.println("\n"+currentPlayer+": Enter a letter: ");
    
    currentGuess=new Scanner(System.in).next();
    
    //usedLetters();
    alphabet();
    System.out.println("debugging(below used letters and alphabet): >"+currentGuess+"<");
    System.out.println("current player:" +currentPlayer+"\n");
        switch(currentGuess.toUpperCase())
        {
        case "A":
        int a=9;
        letterValue =9;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        case "B":
        int b=2;
        letterValue =2;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        case "C":
        int c=9;
        letterValue =9;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        case "D":
        int d=4;
        letterValue =d;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "E":
        int e=12;
        letterValue =e;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "F":
        int f=2;
        letterValue = f;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "G":
        int g=3;
        letterValue =g;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "H":
        int h=2;
        letterValue =h;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "I":
        letterValue =9;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "J":
        int j=1;
        letterValue =j;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "K":
        int k=1;
        letterValue =k;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "L":
        int l=4;
        letterValue =l;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "M":
        int m=2;
        letterValue =m;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "N":
        int n=6;
        letterValue =n;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "O":
        int o=8;
        letterValue =o;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "P":
        int p=2;
        letterValue =p;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "Q":
        int q=1;
        letterValue =q;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "R":
        int r=6;
        letterValue =r;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "S":
        int s=4;
        letterValue =s;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "T":
        int t=6;
        letterValue =t;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "U":
        int u=4;
        letterValue =u;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "V":
        int v=2;
        letterValue =v;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "W":
        int w=2;
        letterValue =w;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "X":
        int x=1;
        letterValue =x;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "Y":
        int y=2;
        letterValue =y;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        
        case "Z":
        int z=1;
        letterValue =z;
        System.out.println(">Value of "+currentGuess.toUpperCase()+" is "+letterValue);
        
        break;
        default:
        System.out.println("Only permitted to use a single character.");
        startGame();
        break;
        }
    }
        System.out.println("\nRemaining letters are: \n"+alphabet());
        playerOneTurn();
        System.out.println("debugging: below Switch statement>"+currentGuess+"<");
    //}
        //currentGuess.equals(" ");
        //currentPlayer();
        //startGame();
//}
        //System.out.println("You have chosen to exit the game.");
        //finalScores();
        
}
            private static void playerOneTurn()
        {
            System.out.println("debugging:inside player one Turn >"+currentGuess+"<");
            //if(currentPlayer==playerTwo){
            //playerTwoTurn();
        //}
        
            playerTurnScore=playerTurnScore -duplicateLetterValue;
            playerLetter+=currentGuess;
            System.out.print(currentPlayer +"'s word is: "+playerLetter);
            System.out.println("\nEnter (Y) if both players agree on the word or anything else if you disagree: ");
            Response=new Scanner(System.in).next();
            
            if(Response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")&&currentPlayer == playerOne)
        {

            System.out.print("\nPlayer one score has changed.");

            playerOneScore+=playerTurnScore;
            
            System.out.println("\nPlayer one Score: "+playerOneScore+"\n");
            playerLetter="";
            
            currentPlayer();
            startGame();

            

            }else if(Response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")&&currentPlayer == playerTwo)
            {
    
            playerTwoTurn();    

            }else{
            System.out.println("Word denied.");
            System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        
        private static void playerTwoTurn()
        {
            System.out.println("inside player two turn >"+currentGuess+"<");
            currentPlayer();
            System.out.println("\nNext Turn is: "+currentPlayer);
            
            guessedLetters += currentGuess;
            System.out.print("Overall used letters: "+guessedLetters);
            System.out.print("\nPlayer two score has changed.");
            playerTwoScore+=playerTurnScore;
            System.out.print("\nPlayer two Score: "+playerTwoScore);
            startGame();
        }
    
private static String alphabet()
{
    System.out.println("debugging:underneath alphabet string. >"+currentGuess+"<");
    for(int i=0;i<alphabet.toCharArray().length;i++){
            if(currentGuess.contains(alphabet.toCharArray()[i]+""))
            {   
                System.out.println("debugging: >"+currentGuess+"<");
                alphabet=alphabet.replace((alphabet.toCharArray()[i]+""), "test");
                
            }else if(currentGuess.contains(Vowels.toCharArray()[i]+""))
            {
            System.out.println("You have just entered a Vowel, board not affected.");
            }
}   
return alphabet;
}
private static void currentPlayer()
    {
    if(playerNumber==1)
        {
            currentPlayer=playerOne;
            playerNumber+=1;
        }
        else{
            currentPlayer=playerTwo;
            playerNumber-=1;
        }
    }
    
    private static void finalScores(){
    
        if(playerOneScore>playerTwoScore){
        System.out.println("Player one wins.");
        System.exit(0);
        }else{
        System.out.println("Player two wins.");
        System.out.print(playerTwoScore);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private static void usedLetters()
{
    for(int i=0;i<currentGuess.toCharArray().length;i++)
    {
        if(guessedLetters.contains((currentGuess.toCharArray()[i]+"")))
        { 
            //currentGuess=currentGuess.replace((currentGuess.toCharArray()[i]+""), "");
            System.out.println(">Those letters were previously used.");
            playerTurnScore=playerTurnScore-duplicateLetterValue;

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO.  To make your experience better:  1) don't post links to images of code. 2) read [ask], 3) post a [MCVE]

Comment: Your code includes much too much that has nothing to do with your problem. Also, to better understand this, could you please add the input value, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: @NomadMaker input Value would be H, i expect the output to be _ but instead it is still H, it isn't replaced like it should. It only replaces 7 characters and says hell to the rest. You can throw my code into a compiler yourself, also if you want me to exactly pinpoint the problem area then i can only give you an assumption unfortunately. That first bit of code is where the replacement is meant to take place, but rather only A,B,C,D,E,F,G is replaced when you insert them consecutively

Comment: I can't get to a compiler for a few hours, but why does alphabet have brackets and a newline character in the string?

Comment: Why do you continually create char arrays and immediately index them, rather than just do ``alphabet.charAt(i)`` (rather than alphabet.toCharArray()[i])?

Comment: You do realize that the array of chars for Vowels (which should be vowels) is {'[', 'a', ']', ...}

Comment: @NomadMaker Do you want me to use a character array instead? i have tried to use one but don't know how to replace indexes in this array if someone puts 'a' or 'b' in on a scanner that the right array is replaced. i could do a array[1] = 'a' but then would that not be long unnecessary code? thanks for replying. I also fixed my original problem by using <alphabet instead of <vowels as something to loop with

Comment: I was trying to figure out why you including the square brackets in you alphabet string.

Comment: @NomadMaker they are kind of.. cosmetic, i could take them out but i want an alternative way to separate them. In a perfect world i'd want a 2d array instead :S

Comment: Why would you want a 2d array? You could easily have one if you wanted. The square brackets lead to a potentially large category of bugs.

Comment: @NomadMaker back 2 weeks ago i tried a 2d array, i was just unable to replace an array with a letter using a loop. If i had another crack at it now i may be able but i'm happy-ish enough with what i got. I do think it's basic and i'd rather at least 1 array in my code, lol. I can remove the square brackets too. Have you any ideas on how to make a scrabble game more interesting?

Comment: How to make scrabble more interesting? Try it in with Chinese. With Chinese characters. :)